# Determine the value of the series $\sum _{ n=1 }^\infty \frac1{ ( n+2) n!}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, factorial

Find the partial sum $S_n$ of the telescoping series

$$\sum _{ n=1 }^{ \infty  }{ \frac { 1 }{ \left( n+2 \right) n! }  } $$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

HINT:

$$\frac1{(n+2)\cdot n!}=\frac{n+1}{(n+2)!}=\frac{n+2-1}{(n+2)!}=\frac1{(n+1)!}-\frac1{(n+2)!}$$

Comment: Thank you for providing the requested information.