# Finding the sum of the series $\frac{1}{1!}+\frac{1+2}{2!}+\frac{1+2+3}{3!}+ \ldots$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Deteremine the sum of the series
$$\frac{1}{1!}+\frac{1+2}{2!}+\frac{1+2+3}{3!}+ \ldots$$

So I first write down the $n^{th}$ term $a_n=\frac{\frac{n(n+1)}{2}}{n!}=\frac{n+1}{2(n-1)!}$.

So from there I can write the series as $$1+\frac{3}{2}+\frac{4}{2\times 2!}+\ldots +\frac{n+1}{2(n-1)!}+\ldots $$

I am quite sure I can do some sort of term by term integration or differentiation of some standard power series and crack this. Any leads?

Comment: Write  the numerator as $(n-1)+2$.

Comment: You don't have the correct series exactly, though the general term is okay. The correct series is: 

$$\frac{2}{2\times 0!} + \frac{3}{2\times 1!} + \frac{4}{2\times 2!}+\frac{5}{2\times 3!}+\ldots +\frac{n+1}{2(n-1)!}+\ldots $$

Comment: Related : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/845464/determine-the-value-of-the-following-series

Comment: Related question: [Summation of a series help: $\sum \frac{n-1}{n!}$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/764065/summation-of-a-series-help-sum-fracn-1n)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

HINT: Split
$$\frac{n+1}{2(n-1)!}= \frac{1}{2(n-2)!}+\frac{1}{(n-1)!}$$
and use the fact that $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n!}=e$

Comment: That does it! The sum comes out to be $\frac{3e}{2}$