# what will be the sum of this series $\frac{1}{1!}+\frac{1+2}{2!}+\frac{1+2+3}{3!}+...$?

Tags: sequences-and-series

The sum of the series :
$\frac{1}{1!}+\frac{1+2}{2!}+\frac{1+2+3}{3!}+...$ equals

A) e

B) $\frac{e}{2}$

c) $\frac{3}{2}e$

D) $1+\frac{e}{2}$

I need a hint to deal with this sum, I understood, since the sum of the first n natural number is $\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$, so the $n^{th}$ term of the series is $\frac{\frac{n(n+1)}{2}}{n!}=\frac{n(n+1)}{2n!}$, how should I use this to get the sum...

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: It is greater than $e$.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1334661/42969

Comment: Your sum = $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{k(k+1)}{2k!}$...

Comment: **Hint:** Write
$$\frac{n(n+1)}{n!}=\frac{n(n-1)}{n!}+2\frac n{n!},$$
and play around with the series $e^x=1+\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!}$ (taking derivatives).

Comment: A word of warning, writing $2n!$ could be confusing since some people might incorrectly read that as $(2n)!$ as opposed to $2(n!)$.  Better probably to use parentheses or a multiplication symbol between them to emphasize this.