# How to solve this summation without taylor?

Tags: sequences-and-series

The summation in question  is $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty  \frac{n(n+1)(n+2)}{n! + (n+1)! + (n+2)!}$$

The sum can be simplified further into $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty  \frac{n(n+1)^2}{(n+2)!}$$ With Taylor expansion allowed, I don't think it's hard to derive it from expansion of $e^x$.

Comment: *With* or *Without* ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As $n(n+1)^2$ is $O(n^3),$

write  $n(n+1)^2=(n+2)(n+1)n+ A(n+2)(n+1)+B(n+2)+C$

so that $$\dfrac{n(n+1)^2}{(n+2)!}=\dfrac1{(n-1)!}+\dfrac A{n!}+\dfrac B{(n+1)!}+\dfrac C{(n+2)!}$$

$n=-2\implies C=(-2)(-2+1)^2=-2$

Comparing the coefficients of $n^2,$  $$2=3+A\iff A=-1$$

Comparing the coefficients of $n,$  $$1=2+3A+B\iff B=1-2-3A=2$$

Interestingly, this leads to a [Telescoping series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series),

otherwise, we had to use $$e^y=\sum_{r=0}^\infty\dfrac{y^r}{r!}$$

Comment: Got it.  If it does not telescope then multiple of the exponential term will appear as a result.

Comment: @chanp, See also : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/576976/evaluate-the-series-lim-limits-n-to-infty-sum-limits-i-1n-fracn22/576978#576978  and  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/581603/evaluate-frac13-frac14-frac12-frac15-frac13-dots and  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/845464/determine-the-value-of-the-series-sum-n-1-infty-frac1-n2-n

Answer (score 7):

Hint:  starting from OP's simplification, the following form will telescope nicely:

$$
\begin{align}
\frac{n(n+1)^2}{ (n+2)!} &= \frac{(n+2)(n+1)n - (n+2)(n+1)  + 2(n+2) -2}{(n+2)!} \\[5px]
 &= \frac{1}{(n-1)!} -\frac{1}{n!} + \frac{2}{(n+1)!} - \frac{2}{(n+2)!}
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Both answer are great and correct.  Yours is more direct but the other has more details.

Comment: @chanp The takeaway from either answer (+1 to @ lab btw) is that any polynomial can be written in terms of [falling factorials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falling_and_rising_factorials#Connection_coefficients_and_identities), which is what you'd be looking for in a case like this in order to derive something resembling a partial fraction decomposition (with a chance for telescoping, though that's *not* guaranteed, and in fact rarely happens unless the problem was carefully set up so that it does).