# Find a formula for $\sum\limits_{r=1}^{n} (r^2+1)(r!)$

Tags: summation

The sum  $$\sum\limits_{r=1}^{n} (r^2+1)(r!)$$ 
is equal to:

1. $(n+1)!$
2. $(n+2)!-1$
3. $n\cdot(n+1)!$
4. $n\cdot(n+2)!$

**My work**.  I tried to solve this problem by converting $(r^2+1)$ in squares then applying the property but i was unable to get the solution, please help?

Comment: Try to use $r^2 + 1 = (r+2)(r+1) - 3(r+1) + 2$. The sum telecopes.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/576976/evaluate-the-series-lim-limits-n-to-infty-sum-limits-i-1n-fracn22

Comment: @RobertZ,  I think people should get a fair idea how to address the current problem from that like https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2638073/how-to-solve-this-summation-without-taylor/2638120#2638120

Answer (score 4):

Since there is a factorial, it's better to rewrite $r^2+1$ as suggested above by **Winther's comment**:
$$r^2 + 1 = (r+2)(r+1) - 3(r+1) + 2,$$
then
$$\begin{align}(r^2+1)r!=(r+2)(r+1)r! - 3(r+1)r! + 2r!&=(r+2)! - 3(r+1)! + 2r!\\
&=((r+2)! - (r+1)!) - 2((r+1)!-r!).
\end{align}$$
Now split the sum in two parts and try to simplify.
What do you obtain?

Comment: does this form an telescoping series?

Comment: $$f(r+2)-3f(r+1)+2f(r)=f(r+2)-f(r+1)-2\{f(r+1)-f(r)\}$$

Comment: Yes, it is a telescopic sum.