# How to find the sum of this infinite series?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have the infinite series $1 + \frac{2}{1!} + \frac{3}{2!} + ... $to $ \infty$

My intuition is that $e$ is involved but I don’t know where...

Comment: What techniques have you been taught about to find the sum of other infinite series? We are not here to blindly answer your questions but we can help you get gong or assist if you show us where you are stuck

Comment: Wolfram alpha gives result $2e$

Comment: Trying to find a pattern comparable to other standard series like $e^x$ or $a^x$ and accordingly proceeding.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/576976/evaluate-the-series-lim-limits-n-to-infty-sum-limits-i-1n-fracn22

Comment: Ah, I think I have an idea now : For example $\frac{7}{6!}=\frac{6}{6!}+\frac{1}{6!}=\frac{1}{5!}+\frac{1}{6!}$

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2638073/how-to-solve-this-summation-without-taylor

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Evaluate the series $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \sum\limits_{i=1}^n \frac{n+2}{2(n-1)!}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/576976/evaluate-the-series-lim-limits-n-to-infty-sum-limits-i-1n-fracn22)

Answer (score 3):

Your sum is:

$$\sum_{n\ge1}^{}\frac{n}{\left(n-1\right)!}$$
Setting $n-1 \mapsto n$ gives:

$$=\sum_{n\ge0}^{}\frac{n+1}{n!}=1+\sum_{n\ge1}^{}\frac{n+1}{n!}=1+\sum_{n\ge1}^{}\frac{1}{n!}+\sum_{n\ge1}^{}\frac{1}{\left(n-1\right)!}=\sum_{n\ge0}^{}\frac{1}{n!}+\sum_{n\ge0}^{}\frac{1}{n!}=\color{red}{2e}$$

Comment: This is great! Nice and simple.

Answer (score 1):

Use the definition of the exponential:
$$
\begin{align}
E=&\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac {n+1}{n!} \\
E=&\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac {1}{n!}+\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac {n}{n!} \\
E=&e+\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac {1}{(n-1)!} \\
E=&e+\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac {1}{n!} \\
\implies E=&2e
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 0):

Break each term as $\frac{n}{(n-1)!}=\frac{1}{(n-2)!}+\frac{1}{(n-1)!}$ now just add these two series of the form $\sum \frac {1}{(n!)}=e$