# How do I calculate the sum of $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{x^{n}\over n!}\cdot{{x^2\over n+2}}?$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, power-series

How do I calculate the sum of $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{x^{n+2}\over (n+2)n!}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\color{red}{x^{n}\over n!}\cdot{{x^2\over n+2}}?\tag1$$

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{x^{n}\over n!}=e^x\tag2$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

$$\dfrac{x^{n+2}}{(n+2) n!}=\dfrac{(n+1)x^{n+2}}{(n+2)!}=\dfrac{(n+2-1)x^{n+2}}{(n+2)!}$$

$$=x\cdot\dfrac{x^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}-\dfrac{x^{n+2}}{(n+2)!}$$

$$\implies\sum_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{x^{n+2}}{(n+2) n!}=x\sum_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{x^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}-\sum_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{x^{n+2}}{(n+2)!}$$

Now use $e^y=\sum_{r=0}^\infty\dfrac{y^r}{r!}$

Comment: $\sum_{r=0}^{\infty}{x^{r+1}\over (r+1)!}=?$ @Lab...

Comment: @GiantLeap, $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{x^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}=-\dfrac{x^{-1+1}}{(-1+1)!}+\sum_{n=-1}^\infty\dfrac{x^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}=?$$

Comment: (+1) Nice answer! And better than mine.

Comment: See also : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/581603/evaluate-frac13-frac14-frac12-frac15-frac13-dots and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2638073/how-to-solve-this-summation-without-taylor  and  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/576976/evaluate-the-series-lim-limits-n-to-infty-sum-limits-i-1n-fracn22 and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/845464/determine-the-value-of-the-series-sum-n-1-infty-frac1-n2-n

Answer (score 5):

If $f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{x^{n+2}}{(n+2)n!}$, then $f'(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{x^{n+1}}{n!}=xe^x$. Therefore, since $f(0)=0$, $f(x)=(x-1)e^x+1$.

Comment: no I can't please elaborate more.

Comment: @GiantLeap Integrate both sides of $f' = xe^{x}$

Comment: yeah I see thank you

Comment: @GiantLeap I've added more details.

Answer (score 2):

$$\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{x^{n+2}}{(n+2)n!}=\sum_{n\geq 0}\int_{0}^{x}\frac{z^{n+1}}{n!}\,dz = \int_{0}^{x}\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{z^{n+1}}{n!}\,dz = \int_{0}^{x} z e^z\,dz=\left[(z-1)e^z\right]_{0}^{x}. $$
The exchange of $\sum$ and $\int$ is allowed by absolute convergence.