# Find the sum of the series of $\frac{ 1}{n(n-2)!}$ from $n=2$ to infinity

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I am trying to find the sum of the series from $n=2$ to infinity of $\frac{ 1}{n(n-2)!}$

I was originally given: 1/2 + 1/3 + 1/8 + 1/30 + 1/144 ... ? and I had to figure out the next term (which is 1/840) and then figure out the sum of the series. I deduced what the formula is to make the series but I have no clue how to find the sum. (Brute forcing the sum on a calculator gave me a number very very close to 1 so I'm guessing that's the sum, but I don't know how to find that sum using calculus) Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is
$$\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{(n-1)}{n!}
=\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{n}{n!}-\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{1}{n!}
=\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{1}{(n-1)!}-\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{1}{n!}
=\sum_{m=1}^\infty\frac{1}{m!}-\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{1}{n!}
$$
etc.

Comment: That's a brilliant way of writing it! The part I don't get though is how to find the sum. Normally, ∑n=0->∞ of 1/n! = e   In this case though, we are starting at 1 and 2 respectively.

Comment: @Kaiproberts These are the series for $e$, but in each case with a few terms missing....

Comment: I was being dumb. I just subtracted out the missing terms and got the answer to be 1, thank you so much!

Comment: Is not there a small erratum in the term $-\sum\limits_2^\infty\frac{n}{n!}$, there should be 1 instead of n in the nominator?

Comment: Yeah, I corrected for that on my whiteboard i'm working with and it worked out. Probably just an error from typing too fast.

Answer (score 1):

You already accepted the answer, which is fine. Here is just another way of looking at it:

$$e^x=1+x+\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^3}{3!}+....=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{x^n}{n!}
$$
Now when you divide everything by $x$ and then take derivative on both sides, you end up with:
$$\frac{xe^x-e^x}{x^2}=\frac{-1}{x^2}+1+\frac{x}{2!}+\frac{x^2}{3!}+\frac{x^3}{4!}....=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(n-1)x^{n-2}}{n!}$$
When you plug in $x=1$ and move over $\frac{-1}{x^2}$ to the left side, you arrive at your desired sum, which is indeed $1$ as you suggested.

Comment: I think what threw me off from going this way was that the sum started at 2 instead of 0 for n. I really appreciate this way of looking at it though.

Comment: When you take the derivative, the "first" term is gone, the $-1/x^2$ is moved to the left, which makes the series start with $n=2$...Hope it helps

Comment: Ohhhh, I didn't know that. I'll have to use this for more problems. The deeper I get into math, the more fun it gets.

Answer (score 1):

$$\dfrac{n-1}{n!}=f(n-1)-f(n)$$ where $f(x)=\dfrac1{(x-1)!}$

$$\sum_{n=2}^m\dfrac{n-1}{n!}=f(1)-f(m)$$

Now $\lim_{m\to\infty}f(m)=?$

**See also**: [How to solve this summation without taylor?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2638073/how-to-solve-this-summation-without-taylor)

Comment: Another : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/845464/determine-the-value-of-the-series-sum-n-1-infty-frac1-n2-n

Comment: How does everyone find such interesting ways of solving these kinds of problems? This is a really neat way to look at it too.

Answer (score -1):

$$\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{8}+\frac{1}{30}+\frac{1}{144}+\frac{1}{840}+\cdots=\frac{1}{2}$$

$$\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{8}+\frac{1}{30}+\frac{1}{144}+\cdots=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}=1$$

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! Please elaborate with an [edit] how you you have come to this conclusion. At the moment, it is hard to understand your reasoning.