# Proof that $\sum\limits_{i=1}^\infty \frac{i}{(i+1)!} = 1$

Tags: sequences-and-series, proof-explanation, factorial

I came across this result randomly and am quite sure it's right. Is there any way to prove it rigorously? The numerator always seems to be one less than the denominator. Thanks!

Comment: This is **so** obviously false…

Comment: Are you sure you wrote the exact equation you wanted to write down?

Comment: Do you maybe mean $n = \infty$?

Comment: Indeed n = infinity

Comment: Since $\frac{i}{(i+1)!} = \frac{(i+1)-i}{(i+1)!} = \frac{1}{i!} - \frac{1}{(i+1)!}$, your sum is a telescoping sum.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/845464/determine-the-value-of-the-series-sum-n-1-infty-frac1-n2-n

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\sum\limits_{i=1}^{\infty} \frac i {(i+1!)}=\sum\limits_{i=1}^{\infty} \frac {i+1} {(i+1)!} -\sum\limits_{i=1}^{\infty} \frac 1 {(i+1)!}=\sum\limits_{i=1}^{\infty} \frac 1 {i!} -\sum\limits_{i=1}^{\infty} \frac 1 {(i+1)!}$  If just write the terms you will see that all terms cancel out except $1$.